# Cant post json string to API

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to post json but "description" doesn't work.I have tried to check my json string on "https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print". Whenever i write manually into "description" even if there is special characters it works but when i copy paste. It doesnt work.

> `{
>       "name": "AİRTİES AİR 0205 GIGABİT 5 PORT SWİTCH",
>       "model": "AİR 0205",
>       "manufacturer": "AIRTIES",
>       "categories": [
>           {
>               "name": "Switchler"
>           },
>           {
>               "name": ""
>           }
>       ],
>       "quantity": "0",
>       "description": "Air 205 Türkçe Teknik ÖzelliklerGenel  Standartlar    IEEE 802.3, IEEE 802.3u, IEEE 802.3ab, IEEE
>   802.1pTopoloji    StarProtokol    CSMA/CDVeri iletim hızları  Ethernet: 10Mbps (Yarı Duplex), 20Mbps (Full Duplex)    Fast Ethernet: 100Mbps
>   (Yarı Duplex), 200Mbps (Full Duplex)  Gigabit Ethernet: 2000Mbps (Full
>   Duplex)Ağ medyası (kablosu)   10Base-T: UTP kategori 3, 4, 5 kablo
>   (maksimum 100m)   EIA/TIA-568 100? STP (maksimum 100m)    100Base-TX: UTP
>   kategori 5, 5e kablo (maksimum 100m)  EIA/TIA-568 100? STP (maksimum
>   100m)     1000Base-TX: UTP kategori 5e, 6 kablo (maksimum 100m)
>     EIA/TIA-568 100? STP (maksimum 100m)Port sayısı 5 adet 10/100/1000M
>   RJ45 portuLED göstergeler Güç, Bağlantı/AksiyonTransfer
>   yöntemi   Store-and-ForwardMAC Adresi Algılama    Otomatik algılama,
>   otomatik yıllandırmaÇerçeve Filtreleme Hızı   10Base-T: 14880pps/Port
>     100Base-Tx: 148800pps/Port  1000Base-T: 1488000pps/PortÇerçeve İleri
>   Hızı  10Base-T: 14880pps/Port     100Base-Tx: 148800pps/Port  1000Base-T:
>   1488000pps/PortOrtam Değişkenleri ve Fiziki ÖzelliklerÇalışma ısısı
>   aralığı   0 ~40°C (32 ~104°F )Saklamaya uygun ısı aralığı  -40 ~70°C
>   (-40 ~158°F)Çalışma nemi  10%~90% yoğuşmasızSaklamaya uygun nem
>   aralığı   5%~90% yoğuşmasızAirTies Hakkında: Kablosuz Ağ Teknolojileri
>   alanında pazar liderliği hedefiyle ABD Silikon Vadisi’nden Türkiye’ye
>   dönüş yapan idari ve teknik bir ekip tarafından 2004 yılında kuruldu.
>   AirTies, uzman Ar-Ge ekibiyle, aynı ev içerisinde birden fazla TV,
>   notebook, PC ve oyun konsoluna kablosuz, yüksek çözünürlüklü veri ve
>   medya aktarımı konusunda kendi ürünlerinin donanım ve yazılımlarını
>   geliştiriyor. Ürün portföyünde geniş bant internet cihazları, yerel ağ
>   ürünleri, internet üzerinden telefon, aksesuarlar ve internet tabanlı
>   televizyonlar için set üstü kutular (set top box) yer alıyor. Tek bir
>   düğmeye basarak kablosuz entegrasyon sağlayan ödüllü teknolojisinin
>   yanı sıra evin her noktasında yüzde 100 internet erişimi sağlıyor.
>   AirTies’ın dünya çapında 8 milyondan fazla kurulu sistemi
>   bulunuyor.Marka   AirtiesPort Sayısı  5 PortDiğerGaranti Süresi (Ay)  36
>   ",
>       "currencyType": "USD",
>       "price": "0",
>       "vatRate": "18", "images": [ "https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"  ] }`

This is c# code with restsharp

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("DX-API-KEY", f1.Token());

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

string deger = "{\r\n    \"name\": \"" + item.STOK_ADI + "\",\r\n    \"model\": \"" + item.STOKKODU + "\",\r\n    \"manufacturer\": \"" + marka + "\",\r\n    \"categories\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"name\": \"" + item.ARA_GRUBU + "\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"name\": \"" + item.ALT_GRUBU + "\"\r\n        }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"quantity\": \"" + kalan + "\",\r\n    \"description\": \"" + gercekaciklama + " \",\r\n    \"currencyType\": \"USD\",\r\n    \"price\": \"" + fiyat + "\",\r\n    \"vatRate\": \"" + item.KDV_ORANI + "\",\r\n\"images\": [\r\n\"" + resim + "\" \r\n]\r\n}";

request.AddJsonBody(deger);
```

Comment: just a small tip for the future: a proper IDE would have escaped your JSON on paste and that would not have happend

Comment: why are you creating the json yourself? just use newtownsoft or any other library for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a multi-line string you must replace all line breaks with '\n'

Your current json would look like :

```
{
      "name": "AİRTİES AİR 0205 GIGABİT 5 PORT SWİTCH",
      "model": "AİR 0205",
      "manufacturer": "AIRTIES",
      "categories": [
          {
              "name": "Switchler"
          },
          {
              "name": ""
          }
      ],
      "quantity": "0",
      "description": "Air 205 Türkçe Teknik ÖzelliklerGenel  Standartlar    IEEE 802.3, IEEE 802.3u, IEEE 802.3ab, IEEE\n802.1pTopoloji    StarProtokol    CSMA/CDVeri iletim hızları  Ethernet: 10Mbps (Yarı Duplex), 20Mbps (Full Duplex)    Fast Ethernet: 100Mbps\n(Yarı Duplex), 200Mbps (Full Duplex)  Gigabit Ethernet: 2000Mbps (Full\nDuplex)Ağ medyası (kablosu)   10Base-T: UTP kategori 3, 4, 5 kablo\n(maksimum 100m)   EIA/TIA-568 100? STP (maksimum 100m)    100Base-TX: UTP\nkategori 5, 5e kablo (maksimum 100m)  EIA/TIA-568 100? STP (maksimum\n100m)     1000Base-TX: UTP kategori 5e, 6 kablo (maksimum 100m)\n  EIA/TIA-568 100? STP (maksimum 100m)Port sayısı 5 adet 10/100/1000M\nRJ45 portuLED göstergeler Güç, Bağlantı/AksiyonTransfer\nyöntemi   Store-and-ForwardMAC Adresi Algılama    Otomatik algılama,\notomatik yıllandırmaÇerçeve Filtreleme Hızı   10Base-T: 14880pps/Port\n  100Base-Tx: 148800pps/Port  1000Base-T: 1488000pps/PortÇerçeve İleri\nHızı  10Base-T: 14880pps/Port     100Base-Tx: 148800pps/Port  1000Base-T:\n1488000pps/PortOrtam Değişkenleri ve Fiziki ÖzelliklerÇalışma ısısı\naralığı   0 ~40°C (32 ~104°F )Saklamaya uygun ısı aralığı  -40 ~70°C\n(-40 ~158°F)Çalışma nemi  10%~90% yoğuşmasızSaklamaya uygun nem\naralığı   5%~90% yoğuşmasızAirTies Hakkında: Kablosuz Ağ Teknolojileri\nalanında pazar liderliği hedefiyle ABD Silikon Vadisi’nden Türkiye’ye\ndönüş yapan idari ve teknik bir ekip tarafından 2004 yılında kuruldu.\nAirTies, uzman Ar-Ge ekibiyle, aynı ev içerisinde birden fazla TV,\nnotebook, PC ve oyun konsoluna kablosuz, yüksek çözünürlüklü veri ve\nmedya aktarımı konusunda kendi ürünlerinin donanım ve yazılımlarını\ngeliştiriyor. Ürün portföyünde geniş bant internet cihazları, yerel ağ\nürünleri, internet üzerinden telefon, aksesuarlar ve internet tabanlı\ntelevizyonlar için set üstü kutular (set top box) yer alıyor. Tek bir\ndüğmeye basarak kablosuz entegrasyon sağlayan ödüllü teknolojisinin\nyanı sıra evin her noktasında yüzde 100 internet erişimi sağlıyor.\nAirTies’ın dünya çapında 8 milyondan fazla kurulu sistemi\nbulunuyor.Marka   AirtiesPort Sayısı  5 PortDiğerGaranti Süresi (Ay)  36",
      "currencyType": "USD",
      "price": "0",
      "vatRate": "18", "images": [ "https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"  ] 
}
```